# XPATH Ruby Nokogiri and substring-after

Tags: xpath

I have HTML with some node like this

```
<span>Website: http://example.com</span>
```

I want to get the text `http://example.com` and I can extract it with xpath

```
substring-after(//span[contains(.,'Website:')],'Website: ')
```

With `Ruby` and `Nokogiri` to extract this info by

```
doc.xpath("substring-after(//span[contains(.,'Website: ')],'Website: ')")
```

But if I use

```
doc.at_xpath("substring-after(//span[contains(.,'Website: ')],'Website: ')")
```

Then it returns

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `first' for "http://example.com":String
```

But I don't want to use `doc.xpath` I want to use `doc.at_xpath` 'cause I don't want to rewrite my function.

How could I do that? Any suggest?
Thank you.

Comment: Note that `substring-after(//span[contains(.,'Website:')],'Website: ')` contains a bug. You should use either `'Website:'` or `'Website: '` consistently.

Comment: You means the text in contains(.,'Website:') and 'Website: ' is different then it can make a bug?

Comment: Yes, obviously. If a string contains `'Website:'` then it's entirely possible that it does not contain `'Website: '`, and therefore also no `substring-after()` it.